# unable to access dash after uninstalling google chrome

Tags: apt, unity-dash, dpkg, multiarch, debconf

After i removed the package google chrome through command `sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-stable`. I couldnot access dash. 
I tried `sudo apt-get install unity-scope-home` command, but it gives me error about unmet dependencies. 
After that i tried `sudo apt-get -f install`, it asked y/n to install `libgcc1` package. But it then gives the error:

```
E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed? 
Debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
dpkg: regarding .../libgcc1_1%3a4.8.1-10ubuntu9_i386.deb containing libgcc1:i386, pre-dependency problem: 
libgcc1 pre-depends on multiarch-support
multiarch-support is unpacked, but never has been configured.

dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libgcc1_1%3a4.8.1-10ubuntu9_i386.deb (--unpack):
pre-dependency problem - not installing libgcc1:i386
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libgcc1_1%3a4.8.1-10ubuntu9_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whole day i researched about this error on askubuntu and other ubuntu and finally i found my answer on a raspberry forum. The solution is as follows:

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/eglibc/multiarch-support_2.17-93ubuntu4_i386.deb
dpkg -i --force-depends multiarch-support_2.17-93ubuntu4_i386.deb
```

after this i installed `libgcc1` package with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libgcc1
```

Through these commands you are correcting wrongly set dependencies for the multiarch-support package

Comment: I was experiencing some related issues, and this helped me, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try reloading unity. In a terminal, type:

```
unity
```

Comment: There are some replies compiz (core) - info: and some replies compiz (decor) - warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct

Comment: The prompt goes dead after printing these andi tried stopping the process with ctrl + z or q but there was no response

Comment: some times this happen to me and I solve by this, you may need additional actions.